# Why am I not getting .CopyToDataTable() in Linq Query()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This following code example is borrowed from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx).  I am not getting query.CopyToDataTable() available in my code. (see the commented line in my following code).

```
public static bool SetPhysicianAsNotonServer(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataTable dtPhysicianServer = dt;
            DataTable dtPhysicianClient = GetPhysicianClient();

            var query =
                from SPhysician in dtPhysicianServer.AsEnumerable()
                join CPhysician in dtPhysicianClient.AsEnumerable()
                on SPhysician.Field<string>("PhysicianNumber") equals
                    CPhysician.Field<string>("PhysicianNumber")
                select new
                {
                    PhysicianNumber = CPhysician.Field<string>("PhysicianNumber")
                 };

            DataTable FilterDt = query; //query.CopyToDataTable();
            //YET TO DO CODE HERE
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: If you try calling `CopyToDataTable()` what error message do you get?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your select statement is returning a sequence of strings (`IEnumerable<string>` or `IQueryable<string>`), not a sequence of DataRows. CopyToDataTable() is only available on `IEnumerable<T>` where T is or derives from DataRow.

Instead of `select new { ... }` - which will just get you a new sequence of that type, try:

```
select CPhysician;
```

Which should return the desired sequence of CPhysician rows.

**Edit**
If you wish to convert a non-datatable-derived T to a datatable, MSDN has a sample class that reflects out any type and performs the conversion.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx

Comment: +1 for the only complete and accurate explanation (while it may be necessary to reference the DataSetExtensions, that won't fix the problem).

Comment: That sounds ok. But please tell me how I gonna get this fixed. If I do this IEnumerable<DataRow> query = //the whole above code, It does not allow me to put Join in Linq Query.

Answer (score 9):

It exists in a specific namespace are you importing it?

```
System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable()
```

Also confirm the addition of this reference

```
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
```

Comment: DataTable.AsEnumerable would also fail if this was not included.

Answer (score 4):

I think that's because your creating a anonymous type to hold the `Field` object.
Try this:

```
    var query = from SPhysician in dtPhysicianServer.AsEnumerable()
                join CPhysician in dtPhysicianClient.AsEnumerable()
                on SPhysician.Field<string>("PhysicianNumber") equals
                    CPhysician.Field<string>("PhysicianNumber")
                select CPhysician;

    DataTable FilterDt = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Definition of `CopyToDataTable<T>`:

```
public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source
)
where T : DataRow
```

So what you select with the query must be of type `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` extends `DataRow`

Comment: Have you tried referencing DataSetExtensions as others have mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly and use the `System.Data` namespace.

Comment: It is not a reference issue. DataSetExtensions assembly is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced System.Data.DataSetExtensions assembly? This extension method is defined there.

Answer (score 0):

Navigating further into MSDN online brings me to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.aspx

It says its in the System.Data namespace (using System.Data) and you need to reference the System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll.

Comment: If that were the problem, then the calls to AsEnumerable would fail, wouldn't they?

Comment: I guess you're right. I did only a little bit of research, and no VS to test in... And I see that @Rex M probably has the right answer to this question :-)

Answer (score 0):

This issue for me was caused by using Dotnet Core 2.0, which appears to have no way to turn an `IEnumerable` back into a `DataTable` after it's converted.

Just adding this for anyone that comes across this question with the same issue.