# CopyToDataTable does not show up as a method in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

New to linq and trying to acheive

```
  select * from tblCountries order by CountryName
```

I followed the procedre in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, and can now access the CopyToDataTable method.

But now there is a syntax error at the orderby part-

```
cannot convert IOrderedQueryable<Context.tblCountry> to Ienumerable<system.data.datarow>
```

code

```
public DataTable GetAllRecords(bool bDeleted)
{
  IEnumerable<DataRow> query = (from p in MedianDB.tblCountries
                              select p).OrderBy(p => p.CountryName);//error here                                        

    DataTable dt = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

    if (dt != null)
        return dt;
    else
        return dt;
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595350/why-am-i-not-getting-copytodatatable-in-linq-query

Comment: What is `MedianDB`? If it's a strongly typed `DataSet` it should work, otherwise not.

Comment: @bump.Thank You, I came here after that but could not comprehend.

Comment: @Tim, I used an data entity model, and MedianDB is the name of the model

Comment: As the comments already suggested, CopyToDataTable only works if your query returns an IEnumerable<T> where T:DataRow.

In your case, it is not, it is an Entity, so here is another suggestion:

How to: Implement CopyToDataTable<T> Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Sadek I followed the method in the link and now can access the copytodatatable method, but now there is a syntax error in linq. I have updated my question.Thank you

Comment: Put the errors/exceptions you are getting in your question.